# How does Eclipse-ADT find JDK Path

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

I am working with the Eclipse ADT+ADK bundle, adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030 on Win 8. I also installed Java JDK 1.6 and i see it was installed in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0
Android ADT is working fine for me (it compiled few projects i tried - hello world and I was able to run this app on device as well)

I know the Eclipse-ADT uses JAVA_HOME variable to locate the JDK, but strangely when I checked my Windows 8 environment Variables there is no JAVA_HOME variable, which puzzled me.

How is Eclipse-ADT getting JDK path?

Also is there any other preference/setting which tells Eclipse ADT about Java ADK path?

Note: I have another JDK 1.7 installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.45

Comment: The important is wheter the path tp JDK is in the windows PATH variable, not what you decide to call it. I think..

Comment: under Preferences>Java>Installed JREs it shows the jres you have installed, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487814/how-does-eclipse-find-the-jre-or-jdk-locaton) for the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

- For Android SDK PATH, you can modify SDK location in subpage Android of dialog 'Preferences' (open it from menu "Window-Preferences").
- For JDK, it's fine if javac can be found from environment variable PATH.